# Save results from pdo query to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to javascript so please be patient with me.
I have a function in php which goes like this:

```
 public function getSubjects() {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, subject from subjects');
            $stmt->execute();                     
            return  $stmt->fetchall();
        }
```

Then I have a variable subs in javascript which is hardocded like this:

```
var subs = {"Maths":1,"Geography":2,"Chmesitry":3,"Literature":4};
```

How do I populate the subs variable with the format above from the getSubjects method?

Comment: It depends. Is the javascript being loaded in the page of that PHP code? Or is it ajax?

Comment: `json_encode` my friend... jay-son-en-code.... http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Also I hope this was just a typo `Chmesitry` ;)

Comment: @FirstOne, yes, the javascript is being loaded in this page

Comment: @IncredibleHat, eh, it is a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert the array to json so it can be used as an array of objects in JS.

PHP:

```
public function getSubjects() {
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, subject from subjects');
    $stmt->execute();                     
    return json_encode($stmt->fetchall());
}
```

In javascript:

```
var subs = <?php echo getSubjects(); ?>;
console.log(subs);
```

Comment: You don't need to run `JSON.parse` here. In fact it'll cause an error if you do.

Comment: Are you sure? json_encode returns a string and that string needs to be parsed into the subs object as an array...

Comment: @DanielH. It's easy to test: run both and check the generated source code / console. (I'm not iainn)

Comment: The `subsJson` JS variable isn't a string though, you're outputting an object directly. Trying to parse it again is going to cause an error.

Comment: To add to @iainn's comment: it's not a string cause there is no quotes surrounding it. The generated json will be output in raw as javascript source code, which is (roughly) how you define objects in javascript.

Comment: Right. my mistake.. adding the quotes now

Comment: Well, hm, still not what was proposed, but at least it should work now.

Comment: Oh!! damn I am dense.